# Compile c++17 with g++ (or update g++)?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, filesystems

I have a program that needs the `<filesystem>`libary which is only a included in c++17 and above.
When i compile like so g++ `-std=c++17 -o name name.cpp` it gives me this error `passwordmanger.cpp:4:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory #include <filesystem>`
I've read that in g++ version 6.3.0 and under its `#include <experimental/filesystem>`and that is the version i am running.
So can anyone lead me in the direction of the original source?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you running version 6.3.0? If so you can only use the experimental (TS) version of the library. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Unless you're planning on rebuilding all of libstdc++ yourself, from the ground up, with the complete source, both header files and cpp files, having the source to just the header file will not accomplish anything. The current version of gcc is 11, with gcc 12 just around corner. Just update to a current Linux distribution, which will install gcc 11.

Comment: My advice is to upgrade to a newer version of g++. If  you are on MSWindows and using MinGW use msys2.org to install a current version of MinGW. Related: [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)  my MinGW returns this `gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)`

Comment: Thank you drescherjm i haven't been able to locate the original source for g++

Comment: Here is a question talking about installing MinGW using msys2: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Comment: You have to explicitly link filesystem I forget the syntax